# Is there a "gun control" style lobby against wands in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, government

Seems like most anyone with enough gumption can acquire a wand, read some books, and learn some pretty gnarly spells, including Killing Curses.

This is pretty similar to everyone owning a gun. In fact it's worse because wands seem easier to get and Killing Curses can be learned on one's own.

Is there any sort of lobby or group that is for *wand control*? The group presumably vies for background checks, limitations, and oversight. Maybe some more extreme groups would want wands outlawed all together.

Comment: I have an answer to this, but it would include evidence from later books.  What should I do?

Comment: @CHEESE Spoiler tags. :)

Comment: But you wouldn't be able to actually enjoy most of the answer...

Comment: @CHEESE I've seen all the movies, just never read the books. Have no fear

Comment: All right.  My answers are book-based, but they should be satisfactory.

Comment: Wands are not primarily offensive weapons. They're tools mostly used for mundane tasks in everyday life (doing the laundry, lighting your way etc.). Although there is 'wand control' insofar as under 11s aren't allowed them and Hogwarts students can't use them over the summer.

Comment: A comparison with cars would make more sense (can be used to kill, but mostly serve other purposes).

Comment: Would you like the British Version or the American version?

Comment: Aren't certain, errrm, races (?) banned from possessing wands?

Comment: A better analogy would be cars.  Their primary purpose is constructive, but they can be used destructively.

Comment: @TheDarkLord: Knives are tools too, but there are a lot of regulations about which kind of knife and how you can carry in the street.

Comment: Doesn't one of the books mention in passing that wand ownership became a legally protected right during the Dark Ages because Muggle persecution made them necessary for self-defense?

Comment: I'm guessing that some skill goes into casting killing curses, thereby turning a wand into a weapon of death. And there are very, very many legal objects that can also function as weapons of death in the hands of someone able and willing. Including lawn mowers, fire extinguishers, and high quality hardwood chairs.

Answer (score 25):

Wands are snapped.  When Hagrid got expelled from Hogwarts, they snapped his wand.  He's not supposed to use magic:

> "Oh, well -- I was at Hogwarts meself but I -- er -- got expelled, ter
>   tell yeh the truth. In me third year. They snapped me wand in half an'
>   everything.
>
> ---
>
> "Yeah -- but we'll go back in this. Not s'pposed ter use magic now I've
>   got yeh."

From *Harry Potter and the Sorcere's Stone.*

In addition, in book 3, Sirius has no wand; he has to use Ron's wand and Snape's, later on.

In book 5  we see:

> “The Ministry does not have the power to expel Hogwarts students,
>   Cornelius, as I reminded you on the night of the second of
>   August,” said Dumbledore. “Nor does it have the right to *confiscate
>   wands **until charges have been successfully proven***, again, as I reminded
>   you on the night of the second of August. In your admirable
>   haste to ensure that the law is upheld, you appear, inadvertently I am
>   sure, to have overlooked a few laws yourself.”

(Emphasis mine)

So there is wand control when someone is arrested and expelled.  On the other hand, you don't need a license to get a wand--Muggle-borns certainly don't have them.  It's only after you do things wrong that they take it away.

The only thing I could find on people being not satisfied with the wand use regulations are goblins (and other non-humans who care), who are not able to use wands.  Otherwise, everyone seems to be happy with the current systems.

Comment: There's also evidence in the books (and movies, I think) that your wand can be used as identification. Doesn't the gang uses Bellatrix's wand as id when infiltrating Gringotts? Also, magic doesn't *necessarily* require a wand, so I figure more general regulation of magic is used. I don't have any concrete to back that up though.

Comment: This actually doesn't provide an answer to the question if there is a "wand control" **lobby**. (but still it is helpful) Do you have something answering the lobby part?

Comment: @TGar Could you explain to me how this doesn't answer the question, because that isn't clear to me.

Comment: @CHEESE You've answered whether or not it exists (one part of the question), but not whether there's a group of witches and wizards (lobbyists) arguing/campaigning for it to exist (the other part).

Comment: @CHEESE What Anthony Grist wrote is exactly what I meant. You answered (and well answered I think) only one part of the question. I suppose that there aren't any canon (like PMar wrote in his answer) evidence about any lobbies, but I don't know HP world that well. I am curious (and OP probably either) if that is true (of course maybe you also don't know, but you can mention it at least if it is that case).

Comment: @TGar Okay, I didn't realize that was a part of the question.  I'll see if I can find anything.

Answer (score 9):

Nothing in canon, of course, but I would have to think there would not be any such group.  The key issue is that wands are essentially required for ALL magic, not just for attack spells (or at least, using magic is much harder without wands).  Lobbying for 'wand control' seems tantamount to *lobbying for magic-users to not use magic* - which, for a community *based on magic*, is absurd.

If we interpret 'wand control' more weakly - e.g only in terms of waiting periods and background checks - that won't work because nearly all new wands are issued to children about to enter school, making background checks nearly pointless (no background!) and waiting periods undesirable ('What do you mean, *you came to Hogwarts without a wand*??  How do you expect to do your classwork?'.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF:SEE. Your answer is fine but try to support your answer with quotes and sources whenever possible to avoid speculation.

Comment: @MatrimCauthon Supporting quotes are good, but this person did say "Nothing in canon."  In fact there is something in canon (see my answer), but quotes aren't necessary if a reason is provided for their absence.

Comment: @CHEESE which is why I asked him to put them in whenever possible. If is does not fit, do not put it in. It is worth Pmar knowing  that the best answers usually have some sort of quote in them.

Comment: @MatrimCauthon If Pmar hadn't known Pmar wouldn't have said "Nothing in canon."

Comment: Saying "that won't work because nearly all new wands are issued to children about to enter school, making background checks nearly pointless (no background!)" is illogical.  It is true that even the most evil future criminals are usually still innocent and harmless at the age of 11.  But it is hardly true that they don't have any background or past life experiences.   Kids as old as 11 have lived longer than more than half of all the humans who ever lived.

Comment: @M.A.Golding: background checks look at things like employment history (child labor laws make that highly unlikely for an 11-year-old), credit history (not an option for a minor), and criminal history (again, not a possibility for a minor - juvenile court records are not made public). So a background check on a minor **is**, in fact, nearly pointless.

Comment: I wonder if that's how muggle-borns *actually* came around - sometime in the past, their grand-grand-grandparents decided that magic was too dangerous, and living in a community of mostly unrestricted wand access was undesirable, and dropped magic altogether. Only by the point their legacy and objections are forgotten would you get a "muggle-born".

Answer (score 6):

### Great Britain

Although there doesn't seem to be much legislation about wand ownership, we do see that people lose the right to bear wands upon getting expelled from Hogwarts, and that other races are banned from owning wands.

> “Why aren’t you supposed to do magic?” asked Harry.
>   “Oh, well — I was at Hogwarts meself but I — er — got expelled, ter tell yeh the truth. In me third year. They snapped me wand in half an’ everything. But Dumbledore let me stay on as gamekeeper. Great man, Dumbledore.”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* - Chapter Four)</sub>
>
> ---
>
> The Wand Ban of 1631, which forbade Non-Human Magical Beings to carry wands.
>   <sub>(W.O.M.B.A.T. Grade Three)</sub>

### United States

The American wizarding government had much stricter wand-control and required wand permits.

> Legislation introduced at the end of the nineteenth century meant that every member of the magical community in America was required to carry a ‘wand permit’, a measure that was intended to keep tabs on all magical activity and identify the perpetrators by their wands.
>   <sub>[Magic in North America - A History of Magic in North America](https://www.pottermore.com/collection-episodic/history-of-magic-in-north-america-en)</sub>

At one point this was going to even be a plot point of the recent *Fantastic Beasts and Where To Find Them* movie, as demonstrated by [this deleted bit of dialogue](https://youtu.be/W6ZP8axYo70?t=970) which appears in the Lego game.

> Seraphina Picquery: You go too far, Mr Scamander! There are no Obscurial in America! We register every birth, every wand...

Comment: by "the movie" do you mean FBAWTFT?

Comment: @RedCaio - Yeah, should I have specified? I assumed it was somewhat obvious.

Comment: Well, the question wasn't tagged for FB, it's tagged HP. So, if you say "the movie" but you actually mean the _FB_ movie (and not a _HP_ movie), then I think it's good to clarify. Remember that beginning fans come here too, ones who might be unfamiliar with FB and it's American setting  :)

Comment: @RedCaio  - Fair point.

Answer (score 1):

## The International Confederation of Wizards allows wizards wands.

Wizards are granted the right to have a wand, and only in extreme cases does their right to have one be taken away (we see this with Hagrid - he’s not thrown in jail but his wand is snapped). Most wizards who aren’t in jail retain the right to carry a wand. The International Confederation of Wizards has guaranteed wizards the right to carry their wands at all times since 1692.

> “<sup>2</sup> The right to carry a wand at all times was established by the International Confederation of Wizards in 1692, when Muggle persecution was at its height and the wizards were planning their retreat into hiding.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Quidditch Through the Ages*</sup></sub>

Wizards who break the law, once they’ve finished their education, seem to be sent to prison, not have their right to a wand revoked. When they’re in prison they don’t have wands, but they seem to regain their wand rights once their sentence is served - there’s no mention of convictions including permanent bans on wand use, including when the sentence is a serious one. When Morfin Gaunt finishes his sentence in Azkaban for attacking Muggles, he has a wand.

> “But then there came a loud knock on the door and the man jerked awake, raising a wand in his right hand, and a short knife in his left.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 17 (A Sluggish Memory)*</sup></sub>

If there’s any lobby for ‘wand control’ past what’s already mentioned of extreme cases, it’s unlikely to get very far. Most wizards would be unwilling to give up their right to own a wand, so it’s not likely that many of them would want ‘wand control’ to be put into place.